# Coffeescript jQuery each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I'm relatively new to Coffeescript and am running into some issues that I think are to do with skinny arrow vs fat arrow / _this vs this vs $(this).

I have the following class and constructor:

```
class @scenarioEditPage
  constructor: ->
    @getParentAttributes()
```

and @getParentAttributes() is

```
getParentAttributes: ->
    @properties = {}
    $("#form_configurable").find('input[type=hidden]').each (index, element) =>
      @properties[$(element).attr('id')] = element.val()
```

Essentially what I'm trying to do is loop through all hidden fields in a form and assign their value to a key/value pair in the properties hash that can be used later. Example: hidden input field with `id=some_id` and `value=some_value` becomes `properties[some_id] = some_value`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I wouldn't use `class @scenariosEditPage` unless you really have to. `class ScenariosEditPage` would be better.

Try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/y6bgrfn2/

```
    class Test
        constructor: () ->
            @data = {}
            @loadData()

        loadData: ->
            $inputs = $("#container input").each (index, elem) =>
                $elem = $ elem
                @data[$elem.attr('id')] = $elem.val()

        getData: -> @data

    $(document).ready () ->
        test = new Test()
        console.log test.getData()
```

jQuery's `each` method changes the context of the inside code, so basically you have to use double arrow to preserve the context or simple arrow with with extra variable, for example `ctx = @`, check this:

```
    # We have some method @doAnything, so :
    @doAnything
    # isnt undefined...

    # Now:
    # this works
    $('selector...').each (index, elem) =>
        # @ == this == caller's context
        @doAnything $(elem)

    # or this works fine
    ctx = @
    $('selector...').each () ->
        # this == DOM Element
        # ctx == caller's context
        # ! ctx isnt @ !
        ctx.doAnything $(this)

    # this doesnt work
    $('selector...').each () =>
        # @ == DOM Element, so @doAnything is undefined
        @doAnything $(this)
```

And you have small bug in your code:

```
    @properties[$(element).attr('id')] = element.val()
```

element.val() is `undefined`, fix it like this:

```
    @properties[$(element).attr('id')] = $(element).val()
```

or better:

```
    $element = $ element
    @properties[$element.attr('id')] = $element.val()
```